# Questions about deletion errors in connecting sqlite3 using python tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite

```py
    def create_table(conn):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students
                       (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT UNIQUE)''')
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counseling_records
                          (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, student_id INTEGER, title TEXT, counseling_text TEXT, record_datetime TEXT,
                           FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(id))''')
        conn.commit()
```

Call through the create_table function,
There are some intermediate functions, but I'd like to omit them and delete the title and record_`datetime` of the `counselling_records`.

However, if you delete it by `RUN`, you can delete it, but if you delete it again, the data still remains. I don't think DATABASE can delete it smoothly.

What's the reason?

this is delete_student function:

```py
    def delete_student():
        selected_index = student_listbox.curselection()
        if selected_index:
            student_name = student_listbox.get(selected_index)
            confirmed = messagebox.askyesno("확인", f"{student_name}을(를) 삭제하시겠습니까?")
            if confirmed:
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                # 학생이름으로 학생 id 조회
                cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM students WHERE name=?", (student_name,))
                student_id = cursor.fetchone()
                if student_id:
                    # 학생과 관련된 상담 기록 삭제
                    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM counseling_records WHERE student_id=?", (student_id[0],))
                    # 학생 삭제
                    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE id=?", (student_id[0],))
                    conn.commit()
                    student_listbox.delete(selected_index)
                    messagebox.showinfo("알림", f"{student_name}이(가) 성공적으로 삭제되었습니다.")
                else:
                    messagebox.showwarning("경고", f"{student_name}을(를) 찾을 수 없습니다.")
```

Wishing for the smooth operation of the delete function.